# How do I run Internet Explorer on a Windows computer from a Linux VM based on the same computer?

Tags: linux, windows, selenium, robotframework

I'm working on a Linux virtual machine on a Windows computer and doing tests on a website using RobotFramework. I would like to open the Internet Explorer browser on this windows computer from my Linux RobotFramework script.

Do you know a way to do this? Thank you.

Previously, I already tried to use Grid Selenium but that did not suit me because the option "timeout" of "open browser" did not work under ExetendedSelenium2library.

Comment: English grammar improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer on your Windows machine hosting the Linux VM is a Windows-compatible binary, so cannot be executed natively under Linux. You can execute Windows-compatible binaries via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) however, but compatibility is [not very good](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25). It's much more common to run Windows in a virtual machine in order to run Internet Explorer, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks tjbp, I will test and search. :)